# My schema for Meteor.users fails validation every time

Tags: javascript, meteor, schema, meteor-collection2

I'm using the collection2 package as seen here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2

I've set up a simple schema wherein only `email` is a non-optional value, but despite this simpleness the validation fails every time claiming that "Email is required".

My schema:

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
  },
  lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
        optional: true
  },
    likes: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
})

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
            optional: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
            regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  verified: {
    type: Boolean,
            optional: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
            optional: true
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true
  },
  services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
  }
})
```

I set it like so:

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User)
```

And just to check it I hardcode a value to add a user with a perfectly fine email address:

```
Accounts.createUser({email: "fdfs@fdsfs.com"})
```

But when I run this a big exception is returned, saying, among other things:

> Exception while invoking method 'registerUser` Error: Email is required
>
> at getErrorObject `<packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:369:1>`
>
> Sanitized and reported to the client as: Email is required [400]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users), `user.emails` is an an array of objects with the properties `verified` and `address`.

So try something like this instead:

```
emails: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true
},

'emails.$.address': {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
},

'emails.$.verified': {
    type: Boolean
},
```

Comment: And then what do I type in `Accounts.createUser`? Edit: Nevermind, I didn't have to change anything. Thanks!

Comment: @Yeats Same as before. `createUser` transforms and (I belief, also) verifies the object that is passed to it. Check [the docs for further info](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)